# Autofilling inputs and selects with select2

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

i got this [Bootstrap HTML code](http://jsfiddle.net/e01tmzew/2/) which for one reason or the other, its not working properly. i want someone help me do this:

1. when a client selects to fill the president select, the other disabled input belonging to the running mate should be automatically filled
2. when they fill the faculty representative select, the other select below should be filled with the appropriate names belonging to that faculty

here is my code

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">  <dt>President</dt> 
    <dd>
        <select data-placeholder='President' class="select11" style="width: 300px;">
            <option></option>
            <option value="AK">Janes</option>
            <option value="HI">Charles</option>
            <option value="CA">Michel</option>
        </select>
    </dd>
    <dd>
        <input id="" placeholder="running mate" class="form-control" type="" name="" style="width: 300px;" disabled>
    </dd>
</dl>
<dl class="dl-horizontal">  <dt>Secretary General</dt> 
    <dd>
        <select data-placeholder='Secretary General' class="select11" style="width: 300px;">
            <option></option>
            <option value="AK">Janes</option>
            <option value="HI">Charles</option>
            <option value="CA">Michel</option>
        </select>
    </dd>
</dl>
<dl class="dl-horizontal">  <dt>Faculty representative</dt> 
    <dd>
        <select data-placeholder='Choose Faculty' class="select11" style="width: 300px;">
            <option></option>
            <option value="AK">Fist</option>
            <option value="HI">BCom</option>
</select>
    </dd>
    <dd>
        <select data-placeholder='Faculty representative' class="select11" style="width: 300px;">
            <option></option>
            <option value="AK">Name</option>
            <option value="HI">Another name</option>
        </select>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: You want us to write all the code for you? You should search and try and repeat to get results. If not, then come to stackOverflow and ask someone to help, not to do all the work!

Comment: +hello Rameen, it was my mistake not including the fact that i tried solving this for the past 4 days....thats a snippet from another code i am writting

Comment: Hi, actually its Raeen and again you are only showing the `html`. I meant the actual `jQuery` code you tried. Use it in your fiddle and let us try to edit and check for errors.

Comment: +i had not seen the select2 events, and they helped me solve the 1st problem, how do i solve the second problem of filling the select2 options dynamically on the fly? please check my edited [jsfiddle...Edited code](http://jsfiddle.net/e01tmzew/3/)

Comment: +sorry, tis is the link, the previous didnt update....http://jsfiddle.net/e01tmzew/4/